# inline block issues

Tags: css

Can anyone provide any good examples of how to use inline-block versus just regular display inline? I'm having trouble grasping the concept, if anyone can do a little demo on jsfiddle why you would use one over the other, that'd be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I Hope Below link should be more helpful for you.

http://dustwell.com/div-span-inline-block.html

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A couple of differences:

1. `inline-block` elements don't wrap onto new lines
2. `inline-block` elements can have `padding` and `margin` applied with expected results.